# expand all and collapse all does not work in all cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a slight issue with my expand all/collapse all feature.

Here is my jsfiddel link:

http://jsfiddle.net/HqXMN/10/

Lets say expand Name1 and Name2 and then hit Expand all button,
What it does is it expands everything but collapses Name1 and Name2.

Do I specify the css id in my javascrit function?

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.expandcollapse', function(e) {
        $('.collapse').each(function(index) {
            $(this).collapse("toggle");
        });

        if ($(this).html() == "<i class=\"icon-white icon-plus-sign\"></i> Expand All") {
            $(this).html("<i class=\"icon-white icon-minus-sign\"></i> Collapse All");
        }
        else {
            $(this).html("<i class=\"icon-white icon-plus-sign\"></i> Expand All");
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: This is because you are using `.toggle()`, which means the elements selected will be in an "either-or" state. If it's already expanded, it will be collapsed, and vice versa.

Comment: If your HTML has **that** many nested DIVs, you probably will want to simplify it first. There's no reason you can't build this with nothing more than two levels of `<ul>`s.

Comment: thanks..can you provide some similar example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a specific action based on the current state of the button. One way to do this is to assign a specific class to the button when it is in a given state.

**NOTE:** It appears that due to the group management that is in place, the state seems to get mixed up when you use a combination of the expand/collapse all button and the individual controls.

```
$(document).on('click', '.expandcollapse', function (e) {
    // Perform specific action based on current state
    if ($(this).hasClass('collapseAll')) {
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
        $(this).removeClass('collapseAll').html("<i class=\"icon-white icon-plus-sign\"></i> Expand All");
    } else {
        $('.collapse').collapse('show');
        $(this).addClass('collapseAll').html("<i class=\"icon-white icon-minus-sign\"></i> Collapse All");
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gnPcz/1/)**

To turn off group management and see how this works correctly in that scenario, you can do so by either removing `data-parent='#programs-accordion'` on all of your items or putting the following at the top of your Javascript:

```
$('.collapse').collapse({
    toggle: false
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gnPcz/2/)** - No group management

Comment: @ Ruben. one of my requirements is that I dont need any static text in my javascript. Hence I move it to the html file

Comment: your demo doesnt solve my issue. did u post it so that i can get some idea?

Comment: @Micheal What do you mean by *static text*? Also, I explained in my note that I do not believe you can combine the functionality of using group management and expand/collapse all button because of internal states that the plug-in seems to keep. You can turn off group management and it will work as you intend. See my expanded answer.

Comment: @ Ruben..i cleaned up my code lil bit. http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/HqXMN/13/ ..is it possible to add ur logic with my updated code?

Comment: i have added some css..I tried to incorporate ur answer to my jsfiddle above, but i am kinda stuck

Comment: @Micheal If the updated answer I provided did not solve the problem in your question, please explain why. The main issue is that you cannot continue to use `.collapse("toggle")` as the main part of your click handler for the expand/collapse all button because it simply will toggle the state.

Comment: Your answer did solve my problem. But I had to update my code to remove the static text(expand all and collapse all) and put in the html...jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/HqXMN/13 ..Its more of a syntax problem i guess. I shall post another thread for that